# SSRS 2008, formatting percentage to 0% when field value = 0.00 and maintain type for excel?

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

When field value = 0.00, I want to display as 0%, all other times display as normal percentage. I know I can do it using string manipulation but if I do that, I lose the type when the report is exported to Excel and can't have that. I have tried different permutations of 0.00%;0% and #.##%;#%, etc... but they have not worked for me.

Any ideas out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, in the Format property, add an expression: iif(value=0.00, "0%", "0.00%")